# Display picklist values after they have been submitted

Tags: lightning-aura-components, controller

I have a `Close Case` tab with two picklists when performing a close-case action, I'm able to save the values to database. But if I revisit the `Close Case` tab I just get the default values, is there any way of having the picklist displaying the earlier chosen values just as for reference for agent to see what was chosen in the picklist?

```
<lightning:select name="reasonPicklist" label="Case Reason" required="true" aura:id="reasonPicklist" value="{!v.objDetail.Reason}" onchange="{!c.pickProblemOption}">
        <option value="">--None--</option>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.reasonOptions}" var="val">
            <option value="{!val}"  selected="{!val.selected}">{!val}</option>
        </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:select>
    <br/>
    <lightning:select name="problemPicklist" disabled="{!v.disablePickProblem}" label="Problem Type" required="true" aura:id="problemPicklist" value="{!v.objDetail.ProblemType__c}">
        <option value="">--None--</option>
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.problemOptions}" var="p">
            <option value="{!p}" selected="{!p.value == v.record.ProblemType__c}">{!p}</option>
        </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:select>
```

the controler

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {        
        helper.loadCase(component);
    },
    sendDetails : function(component, event, helper){
        const spinner = component.find("fullSpinner");
        if (helper.validateForm(component)) {
            $A.util.removeClass(spinner, "slds-hide");
            const c = component.get("v.record");     
            const userId = $A.get("$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id");   
            const qId = component.get("v.queueSettings.Closed_Cases__c");
            c.OwnerId = qId;
            c.Status = 'Closed';
            c.DetailedStatus__c = '';
            c.AgentWorkingId__c = userId;
            c.Has_Been_Closed__c = true;
            c.Reason = component.find("reasonPicklist").get("v.value");
            c.ProblemType__c = component.find("problemPicklist").get("v.value");
            component.set("v.record", c);
            helper.updateCase(component);
        } else {
            const toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
            toastEvent.setParams({
                "title": "Error!",
                "message": "Please select a value in each field to proceed"
            });
            toastEvent.fire();
        }
    },
    sendDetailsWait : function(component, event, helper){
        const spinner = component.find("fullSpinner");
        if(helper.validateForm(component)){
            $A.util.removeClass(spinner, "slds-hide");
            const c = component.get("v.record");     
            const userId = $A.get("$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id");
            const recType = component.get("v.record.RecordTypeId");
            let qId = '';
            if (recType == component.get("v.recSettings.Saga_Club_Case__c")) {
                qId = component.get("v.queueSettings.Saga_Club_Waiting__c");
            }
            else if (recType == component.get("v.recSettings.Holidays_Case__c")) {
                qId = component.get("v.queueSettings.Holidays_Waiting__c");
            }
            else if (recType == component.get("v.recSettings.Saga_Shop_Case__c")) {
                qId = component.get("v.queueSettings.Saga_Shop_Waiting__c");
            }
            else {
                qId = component.get("v.queueSettings.Generic_Waiting__c");
            }
            c.OwnerId = qId;
            c.Status = 'Waiting';
            c.DetailedStatus__c = 'Waiting for Passenger Reply';
            c.AgentWorkingId__c = userId;
            c.Reason = component.find("reasonPicklist").get("v.value");
            c.ProblemType__c = component.find("problemPicklist").get("v.value");
            component.set("v.record", c);
            helper.updateCase(component);
        }else{
            const toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
            toastEvent.setParams({
                "title": "Error!",
                "message": "Please select a value in each field to proceed"});
            toastEvent.fire();
        }
    },
    pickProblemOption : function(component, event, helper) {
        const controllerValueKey = event.getSource().get("v.value");

        const dependentFieldMap = component.get("v.dependentFieldMap");

        const listOfDependentFields = dependentFieldMap[controllerValueKey];

        if (!listOfDependentFields || listOfDependentFields.length == 0) {
            component.set("v.problemOptions", ['--None--']);
            component.set("v.disablePickProblem", true);
            return;
        }

        if (listOfDependentFields.length > 0) {
            component.set("v.disablePickProblem", false);
            helper.fetchDepValues(component, listOfDependentFields);
        }
    }
})
```

helper

```
({
    loadCase: function(cmp) {
        var action = cmp.get("c.getCaseById");
        action.setParams({ caseId : cmp.get("v.recordId") });
        action.setBackground();
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                cmp.set('v.record', response.getReturnValue());
                this.checkIfAttributesFilled(cmp);
                this.fetchPicklistMap(cmp);
            }else{
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        toastEvent.setParams({
                            "title": "Error!",
                            "message": errors[0].message});
                        toastEvent.fire();
                    }
                } else {
                    toastEvent.setParams({
                        "title": "Error!",
                        "message": "Unknown error"});
                    toastEvent.fire();
                }
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    checkIfAttributesFilled : function(cmp){
        var recType = cmp.get("v.record.Record_Type__c");
        if(recType.includes('Holidays')){
            cmp.set("v.record.Reason", "Holly Holidays");
        }
        else if(recType.includes('Club')){
            cmp.set("v.record.Reason", "S Club");
        }
        else if(recType.includes('Shop')){
            cmp.set("v.record.Reason", "S Shop");
        }

        var reason = cmp.get("v.record.Reason");
        if(reason != undefined){
            var a = cmp.get('c.pickProblemOption');
            $A.enqueueAction(a);
        }
    },
    updateCase: function(cmp) {
        console.log('update');
        console.log(cmp.get("v.record"));
        var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        var action = cmp.get("c.updateCaseInternal");
        action.setParams({ c : cmp.get("v.record") });
        action.setBackground();
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    "title": "Success!",
                    "message": "The record has been updated successfully."});
                $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
                toastEvent.fire();
                $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();               
            }else{
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        toastEvent.setParams({
                            "title": "Error!",
                            "message": errors[0].message});
                        toastEvent.fire();
                    }
                } else {
                    toastEvent.setParams({
                        "title": "Error!",
                        "message": "Unknown error"});
                    toastEvent.fire();
                }
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    validateForm : function(cmp) {
        var listToValidate = new Array();
        listToValidate.push(cmp.find("reasonPicklist"));
        var problem = cmp.get('v.problemOptions');
        if(problem.length > 0){
            listToValidate.push(cmp.find("problemPicklist"));
        }
        var valid = true;
        for(var j = 0; j < listToValidate.length; j++) {
            if(listToValidate[j].get('v.validity').valueMissing){
                listToValidate[j].showHelpMessageIfInvalid();
                if(valid){
                    listToValidate[j].focus();
                }
                valid = false;
            }
        }
        return valid;
    },
    fetchPicklistMap : function(component) {
        const toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        const recTypeId = component.get("v.record.RecordTypeId");
        const action = component.get("c.callSalesforceEndpoint");
        action.setParams({
            "url" : `/services/data/v50.0/ui-api/object-info/Case/picklist-values/${recTypeId}/ProblemType__c`
        });

        action.setCallback(this, (response) => {
            if (response.getState() == 'SUCCESS') {
                const correctResponse = response.getReturnValue();
                const valuesObject = JSON.parse(correctResponse);

                const controllerValuesMap = Object.keys(valuesObject.controllerValues).reduce((finalMap, key) => {
                    finalMap[valuesObject.controllerValues[key]] = key;
                    return finalMap;
                }, {});
        
                const valueMap = Object.keys(valuesObject.controllerValues).reduce((finalMap, key) => {
                    finalMap[key] = [];
                    return finalMap;
                }, {});
                valueMap['--None--'] = ['--None--'];
        
                valuesObject.values.forEach(item => {
                    item.validFor.forEach(key => {
                        valueMap[controllerValuesMap[key]].push(item.value);
                    });
                });
                component.set("v.dependentFieldMap", valueMap);

                const controllerValuesArray = Object.keys(valuesObject.controllerValues).map(key => key);
                component.set("v.reasonOptions", controllerValuesArray);

                // component.find("reasonPicklist").set("v.val", component.get("v.record.Reason"));

                // component.find("problemPicklist").set("v.objDetail.ProblemType__c", component.get("v.record.ProblemType__c"));


            } else {
                const errors = response.getError();

                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        toastEvent.setParams({
                            "title": "Error!",
                            "message": errors[0].message});
                        toastEvent.fire();
                    }
                } else {
                    toastEvent.setParams({
                        "title": "Error!",
                        "message": "Unknown error"});
                    toastEvent.fire();
                }
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    fetchDepValues: function(component, listOfDependentFields) {
        const dependentFields = [];
        listOfDependentFields.forEach((field) => {
            dependentFields.push(field);
        });

        component.set("v.problemOptions", dependentFields);
    }
})
```